# In F#, how to fix a pattern match error with value type "a->'b->Model'

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

(I'm new to F#). I have the following definitions in F#:

```
init i j =
    { Id = Guid.NewGuid ()
      InnerRows = [0 .. 2] |> List.map (Cell.init i j) 
      SelectedInnerRow = None}

 let update msg m =
    match msg with
    | Select id -> { m with SelectedInnerRow = id }
    | Reset -> init
```

where the update function shows the following error on "Reset -> init":
***All branches of a pattern match expression must return values of the same type as the first branch, where here is 'Model'. This branch returns a value of type ''a -> 'b -> Model'***

What does ''a -> 'b -> Model' mean, and how can this be fixed?

Thank you.

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message says: *All branches of a pattern match must return values of the same type*

Your `Select id -> ...` branch returns a value of type `Model`

Your `Result -> init` branch returns the function `init`, which has type `'a -> 'b -> Model` - that is, it takes two arguments of some types `'a` and `'b` and returns a `Model`.

The types don't match. Different types. See?

From the semantics, I am guessing that what you really *want* your `update` function to return is `Model`. If so, you need to give the `init` function its two arguments, so that it returns you a `Model`, and that can be the result of the second branch of the pattern-match expression:

```
| Result -> init 0 0
```

NOTE: I'm not actually sure that `0 0` are correct arguments in this case, I'm just guessing. There is no way to know what they should be without knowing what `Cell.init i j` does and what type of arguments it expects.

You have to figure out what the actual arguments `init` needs here and pass them in.